# Visualize that customer is logged in in B2B area in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

working with Magento 2.4.4

I have customer groups General and B2B.

For B2B customer group I would like to display: "You are logged in in the B2B area" after customer logged in.

How could I possibly solve this?

Does anyone has an idea how I could visualize for customers in frontend that they are logged in in a specific B2B area?

Answer (score 1):

You can just retrieve the current store

First create an observer that will check url

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="redirectcustomer_success" instance="Vendor\CheckUrl\Observer\CheckCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then check if the customer is logged in and on which store

```
/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer){
    //in case you want to filter the behaviour on different url or action
    $currentUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
    $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
   
    $currentStoreCode = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    $isStorePro = $currentStoreCode == 'YOUR_PRO_STORE_CODE';

    if($isStorePro){
        if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            //Do whatever you want there
        }
    }
}
```

This would be with an observer to adapt a specific backend treatment.

If you just want to add a sentence in frontend; then use a Helper with the same code and just call the helper in your template.

Comment: Thank you very much We will check this solution and let you know the result.